# How to keep multiple database info on mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a Saas (sofware as a service) project for dentist. Each dentist will have its own database. When dentist is login should connect to its own database. But I dont have any idea about how can i do it that. For now my system work on only one database. I keep database info on web.config file. How can i work with multiple database?

```
 <connectionStrings> 
    <add name="MYDBConnectionString_karendent" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="SERVER=96.89.127.232; Port=3306; Database=karendent;  User ID=userkarendent; Password=RtFLasfgb1-; Charset=latin5; default command timeout=3000; Connect Timeout=3000;"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: After Login, Save the dentist's own `Connectionstring` in `Session`. While executing the `Query`, pass the `Sql connection` as stored in `session`.

Comment: I used Http.context session but it is not work stable sometimes return null error

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Session["Constring"];` it will return. I used the same scenario in my application. Give `System.Web` reference.

Comment: also I used HttpContext.Session["userinfo"] but it is return suddenly null. I didnot add Current on code because it is not work

Comment: Can u share the Code assigning the session Variable and where u r utilizing that session.

Comment: When user login I add session with this: <code>HttpContext.Session.Add("userinfo", (userinfo.ElementAt(0)).db);</code> and I get data as in my previous comment

Comment: No. Use the following code for assigning `Session` Variable. `Session["userinfo"] = userinfo.ElementAt(0)).db`

Comment: both `set` and `get` the session variable in same project or in different.

Comment: aren't you creating a separate instance of the actual software for each dentist as well? Running it its own environment? Otherwise it's not proper SAAS surely? In theory, setting the correct config should be something done as part of a deployment config. In cloud environments you can automate creation of a new instance for a new user, with a complete software-defined operating environment, with configurable settings such as database config etc. Then also each client's environment is private and separate to them, which should be done ideally for data protection / privacy in most countries

Comment: I do it your sayed but still return null. I think it is have timeout limit. I writed this code on web.config but I think it is not works "<sessionState timeout="3000" />". How can I configure session timeout limit? @ShyamVemula